# Enable to open datepicker when id has period operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to open datepicker dialog box. For this I write inlinde code in html input control. Code looks like this

```
<form:input path="sanctionLoans[${count.index}].sanctionDate"
                                    readonly="${param.readOnly}" 
                                    style="text-align: right; width: 100px;"
                                    onclick="findMinDate()"
                                    onclick="$(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' ,changeMonth: true,changeYear: true }).datepicker('show');"/>
```

This code is working fine and open the dialog. But now I want write this code as function so that I can work with other event also like onselect, onclose like this. For this I write a one function something like this.

```
function findMinDate(event){
    var id = $(event).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    id = id.replace(/\./g, "\\\\.");
    var ele = '#' + id;
    console.log(ele);
    $("#sanctionLoans1\\.sanctionDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' ,    
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
        onSelect: function(endDate) {

          }
        })
        .datepicker('show');
}
```

Now problem with this function, because input control ID contain the period operator(.) so first replace it with '\.'. But after replacing the .(dot) with \. it does not open the dialog box. But If hardcore call it '"#sanctionLoans0\.sanctionDate" then it is working fine. 
Can someone help what wrong in function.

Answer (score 1):

1. This

   ```
   var id = $(event).attr('id');
   ```

   should be

   ```
   var id = $(event.target).attr('id'); //or event.target.id
   ```
2. `id = id.replace(/\./g, "\\.");` as you are passing a variable to the selector.
3. `changeYear: true` misses a `,`

Also, I see you already have `onclick="$(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' ,changeMonth: true,changeYear: true }).datepicker('show');"`, so you dont need to call inline function.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zey9xdt3/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `[` and `]` as well

```
id = id.replace(/(\.|\[|\])/g, "\\$1");
```

---

But you really don't want that you can

```
function findMinDate(event) {
    $(event.target).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
        onSelect: function (endDate) {

        }
    }).datepicker('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$("input [id^='sanctionLoans1'][id$='sanctionDate']").datepicker({..............
..............
})
```

or You can do like this

```
> var id = $(event.target).attr('id');  var tempId = id.split(".");
> 
>  $("input[id^='"+tempId[0]+"'][id$='"+tempId[1]+"']").datepicker({...
> ........ })
```